# How to print a text file to introduction jpanel?

Tags: java

I am making a game and I need to print a text files contents to a jpanel and I don't really understand most of the code that other people give me. this is my code right now.

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MainFile2

{

```
JPanel cards, TheOutcome;

JButton Intro, Begin, Back, Back2, Planet6, DontAttack, Attack, Close, Close2;

JLabel Title;

JPanel YesNo;

int[] Troops1 = new int[12];

int[] GroundVehicles1 = new int[12];

int[] AirVehicles1 = new int[12];

public int Planet = 1;

public MainFile2()

{



    JFrame MainFile2 = new JFrame();



    JFrame YesNo = new JFrame();

    YesNo.setSize(500, 300);



    JFrame OutcomeWindow = new JFrame();

    OutcomeWindow.setSize(1920, 1080);



    MainFile2.setSize(1920, 1080);

    MainFile2.setResizable(true);

    MainFile2.setBackground(Color.gray);



    Intro = new JButton("Introduction");

    Begin = new JButton("Play Game");

    Back = new JButton("Back");

    Back2 = new JButton("Back");

    Title = new JLabel("The Rule Of Space");

    Attack = new JButton("ATTACK!");

    DontAttack = new JButton("Don't Attack");

    Close = new JButton("Close");

    Close2 = new JButton("Close");



    Color Purple = new Color(89, 21, 191);

    Color Neon = new Color(170, 255, 2);

    Color Sand =new Color(209, 159, 79);



    JLabel MainbackGround = new JLabel("");

    MainbackGround.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

    MainbackGround.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Volumes/ANDREW2/The_Rule_Of_Space/Pics/Galaxy_backround.png"));     



    JLabel IntrobackGround = new JLabel("");

    IntrobackGround.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

    IntrobackGround.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Volumes/ANDREW2/The_Rule_Of_Space/Pics/IntroBackround.jpg")); 



    JLabel GamebackGround = new JLabel("");

    GamebackGround.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

    GamebackGround.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Volumes/ANDREW2/The_Rule_Of_Space/Pics/GameBackround.jpeg")); 



    Planet6 = new JButton("");

    //JLabel Planet6 =new JLabel("");

    Planet6.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

    Planet6.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Volumes/ANDREW2/The_Rule_Of_Space/Pics/Planet6.png"));

    //Planet6.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());

    Planet6.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

        {

             YesNo.setVisible(true);

             Planet = 6;

        }

    });



    DontAttack.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

        {

             YesNo.setVisible(false);

        }

    });



    Attack.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

        {

             boolean Outcome = Bttle(6);

             YesNo.setVisible(false);

             if (Outcome == true)

             {

                 OutcomeWindow.setVisible(true);

                 CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) TheOutcome.getLayout();

                 cardLayout.show(TheOutcome, "Win");

             }

             else

             {

                 OutcomeWindow.setVisible(true);

                 CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) TheOutcome.getLayout();

                 cardLayout.show(TheOutcome, "Lose");

             }

        }

    });



    Close.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

        {

             OutcomeWindow.setVisible(false);

        }

    });



    Close2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

        {

             OutcomeWindow.setVisible(false);

        }

    });



    JPanel Win = new JPanel();

    Win.setBackground(Sand);

    Win.setLayout(null);

    Win.add(Close2);

    Close2.setBounds(50, 750, 362, 91);



    JPanel Lose = new JPanel();

    Lose.setBackground(Color.red);

    Lose.setLayout(null);

    Lose.add(Close);

    Close.setBounds(50, 750, 362, 91);



    JPanel Selection = new JPanel();

    Selection.setBackground(Purple);

    Selection.setLayout(null);

    Selection.add(Attack);

    Attack.setOpaque(true);

    Attack.setBounds(160,50,200,75);

    Selection.add(DontAttack);

    DontAttack.setOpaque(true);

    DontAttack.setBounds(160,150,200,75);



    JPanel Menu = new JPanel();

    Menu.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

    Menu.setLayout(null);

    Menu.add(Begin);

    Begin.setBackground(Neon);

    Begin.setOpaque(true);

    Begin.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0, Purple, Color.white));

    Begin.setBounds(779, 216, 362, 56);

    Begin.setForeground(Purple);

    Menu.add(Intro);

    Intro.setBackground(Neon);

    Intro.setOpaque(true);

    Intro.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0, Purple, Color.white));

    Intro.setBounds(779, 335, 362, 91);

    Intro.setForeground(Purple);

    Menu.add(Title);

    Title.setFont(new Font("Desdemona", Font.BOLD,150));

    Title.setForeground(Neon);

    Title.setBounds(425, 37, 1500, 121);

    Menu.add(MainbackGround);

    MainbackGround.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);  



    JPanel Introduction = new JPanel();

    Introduction.setLayout(null);

    Introduction.add(Back2);

    Back2.setBackground(Sand);

    Back2.setOpaque(true);

    Back2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0, Color.white, Color.black));

    Back2.setForeground(Color.black);

    Back2.setBounds(50, 750, 362, 91);

    Introduction.add(IntrobackGround);

    IntrobackGround.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);



    JPanel Game = new JPanel();

    Game.setLayout(null);

    Game.add(Back);

    Back.setBounds(50, 750, 362, 91);

    Game.add(GamebackGround);

    GamebackGround.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);

    GamebackGround.add(Planet6);

    Planet6.setBounds(1000, 500 , 150, 150);



    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());



    cards.add(Menu, "Menu");

    cards.add(Introduction, "Introduction");

    cards.add(Game, "Game");



    TheOutcome = new JPanel(new CardLayout());



    TheOutcome.add(Lose, "Lose");

    TheOutcome.add(Win, "Win");



    MainFile2.getContentPane().add(cards);

    YesNo.getContentPane().add(Selection);

    OutcomeWindow.getContentPane().add(TheOutcome);



    MainFile2.setVisible(true);

    YesNo.setVisible(false);

    OutcomeWindow.setVisible(false);



    Intro.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

        {

             CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();

             cardLayout.show(cards, "Introduction");        

        }

    });

    Begin.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

        {

             CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();

             cardLayout.show(cards, "Game");        

        }

    });

    Back.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

        {

             CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();

             cardLayout.show(cards, "Menu");        

        }

    });

    Back2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

        {

             CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();

             cardLayout.show(cards, "Menu");        

        }

    });

}   

public static void main(String args[])

{    

    new MainFile2();

}

public boolean Bttle(int Planet)

{

    boolean Outcome = true;

    int troops = Troops(Planet);

    int groundvehicles = GroundVehicles(Planet);

    int AirVehicles = AirVehicles(Planet);

    return Outcome;

    //planet value - your armys battle

}

public int Troops(int Planet)

{

    Troops1[6] = 20000;

    int troops = Troops1[Planet];

    return troops;

}

public int GroundVehicles(int Planet)

{

    GroundVehicles1[6] = 100;

    int groundvehicles = GroundVehicles1[Planet];

    return groundvehicles;        

}

public int AirVehicles(int Planet)

{

    AirVehicles1[6] = 20;

    int airvehicles = AirVehicles1[Planet];

    return airvehicles;

}
```

}

Comment: One way is to add a text area to your panel and show the text file in that.  Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: Please remove all the extra blank lines from your code, so we can read it easily.  Blank lines in *some* places are useful, such as between method declarations and between logical blocks of code.  A blank line after *every* line of code provides no benefit and creates difficulty for everyone else who tries to read it.  See also [Java Code Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html).